# Validar si todos los elementos de una lista cumplen una condición en Python

Tags: python

¿Cómo valido si todos los elementos de una lista cumplen una condición?

Por ejemplo tengo una lista [9,20,22,30]
y quiero que me retorne `True` si todos los elementos son menores que 10, no solo si el primero es menor.

Pensé hacerlo así:

```
for elem in lista:
    if elem<10:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

pero esto me retorna true ya que el 9 sí es menor que 10.

Comment: `all( [x < 10 for x in lista] )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo lo que hicistes en el codigo de arriba es comprobar si alguno de los parametros dentro de la lista sea menos que diez.
Lo que te recomiendo es lo siguiente:

```
def menorA10 (lista):
    afirmacionesCorrectas=0
    cantidad_de_parametros=len (lista)
    for elem in lista:
        if elem < 10:
            afirmacionesCorrectas+=1
        else:
            break
    if afirmacionesCorrectas == cantidad_de_parametros:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Luego de eso puedes llamar a la funcion de esta manera.

```
numeros=[2,3,7,8]
a=menorA10 (numeros)
print (a)
```

Esto te dara como resultado `True`.En cambio si escribes.

```
numeros=[20,3,7,12]
a=menorA10 (numeros)
print (a)
```

el resultado te dara `False`

¿Te fue útil?

Comment: No es necesario revisar **cada** elemento; basta con encontrar uno que no cumple la condición. Contaste las afirmaciones correctas, pero ese valor no tiene relevancia ni uso, excepto para determinar `True` or `False`.

Comment: haber el pide que si todos los elementos en la lista sin exceptuar ninguno cumplan una condicion y si es asi retornara `True` y si solo uno es falso retornara `False` al menos eso entendi yo.

Comment: Entendiste bien: cuando encuentras el primer False ya sabes que no **todos** son True, asi que no tienes para que seguir.

Answer (score 3):

Inicias con la variable bandera en True y si alguno de los valores la cambia, retornas, false. Retorna al final del bloque de código solamente:

```
flag = True

for elem in lista:
    if elem > 10:
        flag = False

return flag
```

Seguro hay una forma más pythónica de hacerlo, pero la idea es esta :) Hazte a la idea de no retornar en veinte sitios diferentes de tu código para controlar mejor la salida

Comment: Sería más rápido decir "return False" en lugar de usar un `flag`

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de @Alfabravo es muy buena, sin embargo, tal como él mismo dice, una forma más *pythónica* de hacerlo es usando el método o función incorporada [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), que recorre un iterable y devuelve `True` si todos sus elementos son verdaderos, y `False` en caso que uno de ellos no lo sea.

Sin embargo, la lista que tienes no es de `True` o `False`, pero puedes crear una que indique si el valor de tu lista original cumple la condición de ser menor que 10 o no.

Para ello se usa una comprensión de lista, como la siguiente:

```py
my_boolean_list = [ x < 10 for x in lista ]
```

Esto creará una lista de valores booleanos, con `True` o `False`, dependiendo de si el elemento de la lista original es menor que 10 o no.

Luego, puedes aplicar el método `all()` de la siguiente manera:

```py
resultado = all([ x < 10 for x in lista ])
```

Resultado tomará el valor `True` si todos los elementos la lista son menores que 10 y False si alguno de ellos no lo es.

Podrías escribir una función que devolviera el resultado y que reciba como parámetros la lista de valores y el valor contra el que vas a comparar:

```py
def all_less_than_number(lista, number):
  return all([ x < number for x in lista ])

lista = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]

for i  in range(7, 11):
  print(all_less_than_number(lista, i))
```

Esto imprime:

```py
False # 7, 8 y 9 no son menores estrictos que 7
False # 8 y 9 no son menores estrictos que 8
False # 9 no es menor estricto que 9
True  # todos los valores de la lista son meores estrictos que 10
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema

Comment: Muy bien explicado.

Comment: ¡Gran respuesta!